# setInterval execute on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a stupid question but I have a setInterval that does a save every 30 sec.

```
setInterval(SaveContent(true), 30000);
```

I also tried

```
window.setInterval(SaveContent(true), 30000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(setInterval(SaveContent(true), 30000), 30000);
window. setTimeout(setInterval(SaveContent(true), 30000), 30000);
```

I am not sure why setInterval is executing SaveContent when I refresh the page. I though it was suppose to wait 30sec before doing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
setInterval(function() {SaveContent(true)}, 30000);
```

You cannot pass arguments directly to the function you call so you need to embed it in an anonymous function.

() after the function name invokes it and returns a value, in this case to the `setInterval` function.

Optionally you can call it this way:

```
setInterval(SaveContent, 30000);
```

and then in your function:

```
function SaveContent(b) {

    if (typeof b === 'undefined') b = true;  //defaults to true

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass a function to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){ SaveContent(true); }, 30000);
```

The way you have it now, you are executing `SaveContent(true)` immediately and then passing its return value to `setInterval`.

Comment: OK so that is the answer I cannnot accept til 7 min. but I did something similar earlier. Where I defined a function `function autoSave(){ SaveContent(true)}` and passing that into setInterval `setInterval(autoSave, 30000)` but it did not work.

Comment: Just curious: I posted my answer before this, how come this goes on top with the same points?

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware: They appear in a random order each page load.

Comment: @JackThor If you didn't need to pass an argument to `SaveContent` you could just do `setInterval(SaveContent, 30000);` since `SaveContent` is already a function.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you could use `$.proxy` to pass the function with a predefined argument:

```
setInterval($.proxy(SaveContent,null,true), 30000)
```

Comment: Or use `SaveContent.bind(null, true)`. jQuery definitely doesn’t save you much typing versus a function literal here…

Comment: @minitech: Yeah, that should do too. I usually post answers with native `bind` but then people come and say "it's not compatible with older browsers", but "there's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)", etc, etc..